# Is $x\log\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)$ an even or odd function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, even-and-odd-functions

Is $x\log\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)$ an even or odd function?

$$f(-x)=-x\log\bigl(\cos(-x)\bigr)=-x\log\bigl(\cos(x)\bigr)=-f(x)$$

So it seems an odd function and i've tried to draw the graph too.

But the suggested solution in my book says that it is an even function.

Comment: It is an odd function, which is evident from your calculation and the graph.

Comment: just a comment: you have marked this question as "real analysis", however the stated function is not defined in $\Bbb R$ for values of $x$ such that $\cos x<0$.

Comment: I've tagged this as real analysis because i found this exercise in a book of real analysis simply

Comment: @Masacroso That's no problem as far as real-analysis conscerrns. For a function to be odd/even the identity $f(-x) = \pm f(x)$ only has to hold in the domain of $f$. The domain of $f$ is where $\cos(x)>0$ when speaking in a real analysis context.

Comment: As you have written it it is an odd function, but you should of course take care to make sure that you've read/transcribed correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is an odd function and your argument is correct.